# Be or Is? That is the question

Tags: be

Whether it 'be' or 'is'?

> Whether **it be** comedy, action, or pure narrative, he surgically hones pictures and sound to that perfect place.

Comment: Secondary question: Whether it be comedy, action, or pure narrative, he surgically hones pictures and sound to their perfect place.   ??

Answer (score 3):

*whether it be something, something* is a set phrase in English. So, it is always *be* and can never be *is*. I know the grammar may seem a little bit strange, but like I said this is a set phrase—it's unchangeable. Another variant of this expression which also is equally common in usage is *be something, something* with the word *whether* left out.

Example #1:

> I like all things American **whether it be music, movies or even politics**.

Example #2:

> I like all things Korean, **be it food, culture** or what have you.

From a grammatical perspective, this is a form of subjunctive carried over to modern English from time immemorial. The subjunctive is a mood of verbs expressing what is imagined or wished or possible (dictionary definition). You may not have literally seen or experienced all things that are related to American culture, but if you had been presented with something from America, you would have probably liked it because it's American and you like everything American.

Comment: Hello, Michael. I'm afraid I must disagree that "... it is always _be_ and can never be _is_". Even set expressions can (and are seen to) change in some cases over time. I'm not saying that it's incorrect to use 'whether it be', but must agree with Colin Fine when he says "The usage you are asking about is less common [in the UK]". Probably his "I would say that anybody using it today is being deliberately archaic" is going too far, but I'd normally use the indicative in OP's example: << Whether it's comedy, action, or pure narrative, he surgically hones pictures and sound to that perfect ...

Comment: place.>> I'd agree with Colin (in [an answer he gives to this question over on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117330/whether-it-be-vs-whether-it-is)) that the subjunctive often sounds archaic (or worse, grandiloquent), at least in the UK. But have you any supporting references for _your_ opinions?